# CSS hell, I just want a box with min sizes and 1 pixel gap

Tags: css

Please help to achieve this with CSS:
I have array of text strings, from 1 char to 200 chars.
I need to display them in webpage each in separate box.

- the box flow is similar to text, left to right until the end of page then wrap
- the background color of each box must be cyan.
- minimal width and height must both be 50 pixels
- 1-2 pixel space between boxes (maybe achieve with margin=1)
- there must always be at least two pixels between text and the edge of the box
- text is vertically aligned to middle
- text is horizontally aligned to center
- maximum width of box must be 300 px
- if text does not fit in 50x300 it is cropped inside the box (box will not grow)
- each box should have 1 pixel black border

this must be simple for someone experienced! I already try almost every possible CSS tag; but always something is wrong. I read about CSS boxing, but surprisingly it just made it more compilcated.

```
<style>
z {
    min-width: 50;
    #min-height: 50;
    padding: 1px;
    padding-color: magenta;
    margin: 1px;
    margin-color: red;
    #padding-left: 10px;
    display: table-cell;
    #height: 50;
    #vertical-align: middle;
    #text-align:center;
    background-color: cyan;
    #border: 1px;
    #border-color:green;
    /* padding:10px 10px 10px 10px; */
    border-top:1px solid
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#ff0000 #0000ff;
    outline-style:dotted;
    outline-color:#00ff00;
    outline-width: 1px;
    color: blue;
}
</style>

<html>
    <z>1</z>
    <z>abcdefghijklmnope</z><z>2</z><z>blablablabla</z>
</html>
```

I am pasting this so just you can see how hard and wrong I try.

Comment: what is `z` html tag?

Comment: `<z>` is just a random char. I used `<span>` but then realized the name does not matter as soon as you have the same id in both CSS and HTML. If the solution requires `<span>` or `<div>` I am fine with that.

Comment: I'm not sure a '#' is valid before a property. See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp for more details on how to comment.

Comment: The name **does matter**, for example, you **can't** set `heigth` or `width` with span because that is not a block tag. So all your effort might be right but using the wrong html tag. What tag do you want to use? span?

Comment: I will delete comments when I found the solution, they are temporary.

Comment: I will use any HTML tag, I tried most of them already, and cannot get the desired behavior. can you suggest?

Comment: @exebook You don't make comments with `#` in CSS. Most likely it doesn't work because the browser doesn't know what to do with the line starting with `#` and ignores everything after them.

Comment: Comment is not an issue, my Chrome just ignores the lines that start with # and reads other correct. The problem is the correct combination of styles.

Comment: @DanLister http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your requirements properly but mixture of `float:left` elements with `display:table-cell` will give you text that wraps when it gets to the end of the page but allows both vertical and horizontal center aligning

**html:**

```
<div><span>test</span></div>
<div><span>test 1</span></div>
<div><span>loads of text that wraps if the text goes over 300px in length</span></div>
<div><span>loads of text that wraps if the text goes over 300px in length and will hide extra content if really really long</span></div>
<div><span>a</span></div>
<div><span>Amassivewordwithnospacesthatwillalsowrapifithits300px</span></div>
```

**css:**

```
div 
{
    border:1px solid #000000; 
    background-color:cyan;
    float:left;
    margin:1px 1px 0 0;

    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:50px;
    max-width:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

div > span 
{
    display:table-cell;
    min-width:50px;
    max-width:300px;
    height:50px;
    padding:2px;
    text-align:center;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/up6KC/6/

Answer (score 5):

Ok.

1. Don't use made up/invalid HTML elements or invalid CSS comments. Just because "it doesn't seem it matters", doesn't mean it won't make problems. When your HTML/CSS is invalid it's impossible to tell if that's the problem or not and you'll only get answers that tell you to correct them.
2. CSS requires units on lengths. `min-width: 50;` is invalid and if it's working for you, that just means you aren't writing corrent HTML/CSS and the document is in Quirks mode, meaning the browser emulates old IE errors, which makes debugging just more difficult.
3. There is no such properties as `padding-color` or `margin-color`. Don't make up things. Use a CSS and a validator to check your code. (http://validator.w3.org and http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).
4. Using `display: table-cell;` will just place all elements in one "table row" with no wrapping.

```
<p><span><span>1</span></span></p>
<p><span><span>abcdefghijklmnope</span></span></p>
<p><span><span>2</span></span></p>
<p><span><span>blablablabla</span></span></p>

p {
    min-width: 50px;
    max-width: 300px;

    height: 50px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 1px;

    float: left;
    background-color: cyan;

    border: 1 px solid blue;

    color: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}

p > span {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

p > span > span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/DyzAD/1/

Answer (score 1):

(Refined answer)

It's not display:block that is wanted if height/width is required, as the OP also wants the elements to appear next to each other, then break, so float:left; is required rather than display block;

I have implemented the usage of text-overflow:ellipses; to aid in "breaking" the text so the elements will always have a visual balance and vertical alignment. Maybe you could provide a tooltip or html abbr attribute to display the whole text?

float:left on 'z' on any element will (should) fix your problem.

```
span {
    min-width: 50px;
    max-width:200px;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 1px;
    float:left;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: cyan;
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding:10px;
    color: blue;
    white-space:no-wrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MzKCh/3/

Comment: Thanks seemly, it very close! float:left hint is great. No vertical align yet though

Comment: alignment of height across all elements? You would have to define a set height for all elements, rather than a min/max height.